# Text processing - Modify based off two different files

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I have two files named one.txt containing

```
"297","237","14",NULL,"51.195.14.201","02:00:00:1a:1c:06","255.0.0.0","10.0.10.1","32",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"303","242","14",NULL,"51.195.14.207","02:00:00:a3:03:10","255.0.0.0","10.0.10.1","32",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"323","249","14",NULL,"51.195.14.209","02:00:00:dd:1f:11","255.0.0.0","10.0.10.1","32",NULL,NULL,"net0"
```

and another two.txt containing

```
51.195.14.201, 193.138.35.127, 02:00:00:20:a2:27
51.195.14.209, 193.138.35.128, 02:00:00:20:a2:28
```

If two.txt first field has a line in one.txt that contains the same input on field 5 (has to be exact for example `51.195.14.1` would also conflict with `51.195.14.11`) then the 5th field should be replaced with the 2nd field from two.txt and the 6th field should be replaced with the third field from two.txt. Any lines modified should also have the 3rd field replaced with `19`, 7th field replaced with `255.255.255.0`, 8th field replaced with `193.138.35.1` and 9th field replaced with `24`

The change should look like

```
"297","237","19",NULL,"193.138.35.127","02:00:00:20:a2:27","255.255.255.0","193.138.35.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"303","242","14",NULL,"51.195.14.207","02:00:00:a3:03:10","255.0.0.0","10.0.10.1","32",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"323","249","19",NULL,"193.138.35.128","02:00:00:20:a2:28","255.255.255.0","193.138.35.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
```

Note that some columns contain `NULL` with no quotation marks

Comment: This sounds pretty trivial if you read this with python (`import csv` is your friend), and just go through every line, or cleverly put each line into a dictionary that maps the relevant column to the dictionary containing all columns, then merge the two dictionaries you get from the two files.

A bit of footwork, but not dramatically so. So, where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried so far? We're not really a free code-writing service.

Comment: I can find the line that contains 51.195.14.201 and replace it but no working way of using two lists.

Comment: Not quite sure how I'll interpret that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F', *' -v OFS=',' -v q='"' '
    NR==FNR {a[q $1 q]=$2; b[q $1 q]=$3; next }
    $5 in a {
        $6=q b[$5] q; $5=q a[$5] q; $3=q 19 q; $7=q "255.255.255.0" q;
        $8=q "193.138.35.1" q; $9=q 24 q
    }
    { print }
' two.txt one.txt
"297","237","19",NULL,"193.138.35.127","02:00:00:20:a2:27","255.255.255.0","193.138.35.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"303","242","14",NULL,"51.195.14.207","02:00:00:a3:03:10","255.0.0.0","10.0.10.1","32",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"323","249","19",NULL,"193.138.35.128","02:00:00:20:a2:28","255.255.255.0","193.138.35.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
```

Comment: Thanks seems to be working great.